# What elements are permitted to be nested inside the <nav> element for html5?

Tags: html, semantic-markup, nested, nav

What elements can the HTML 5 `<nav>` element contain?

Comment: I've edited the question to hopefully make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The nav element is a new semantic element. It is meant for navigation or a table of contents. Each nav may include other  HTML elements, particularly lists of links.  The nav element is meant for blocks of links, not for individual links mentioned in textual content or for links in the footer area of a section or article.

It replaces the concept of a  element with a semantic element meant specifically as a navigation area.

As with other new semantic elements in HTML5, there may be more than one nav element on a page. Perhaps global site navigation and secondary level navigation blocks for subsections of a site.  They can be styled with hooks like individual id or class attributes, or using descendant selectors based on where they are nested on the page.

for example these html elements can be used inside of nav:
h1, ul, li, a

Comment: Just to add that the spec is a work in progress and has not been finalized.

Answer (score 0):

The [HTML 5 specification](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-nav-element) defines `<nav>` as:

> The `nav` element represents a section of a page that links to other pages
>       or to parts within the page: a section with navigation links. Not all groups
>       of links on a page need to be in a `nav` element only sections that consist of
>       major navigation blocks are appropriate for the `nav` element. In particular,
>       it is common for footers to have a list of links to various key parts of a
>       site, but the footer element is more appropriate in such cases, and no `nav`
>       element is necessary for those links.

[html5doctor.com](http://html5doctor.com/nav-element/) has a very good description of the element.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nav), the `<nav>` element is permitted to contain elements that are considered [flow content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#flow_content).

> Flow content is a broad category that encompasses most elements...including heading elements, sectioning elements, phrasing elements, embedding elements, interactive elements, and form-related elements.