# Can a nav have its own header?

Tags: html

Is it bad to put a header element directly inside a nav ?

Say I want an horizontal bar with "Site::Page" on the left and the list of links to the articles in my page on the right, is it fine to make it this way :

```
<nav>
  <header>Fruitland::Three common bananas</header>
  <ul><li>Link to kind 1</li><li>Link to kind 2</li><li>Link to kind 3</li></ul>
</nav>
```

or should I rather wrap only the ul in a nav, use a h4 for my left part and a div to bind the whole thing together ?

Comment: Check [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/) or just run your markup through the [html5 validator](http://html5.validator.nu).

Comment: I did run it through the validator, it is valid, thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What elements are permitted to be nested inside the <nav> element for html5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059585/what-elements-are-permitted-to-be-nested-inside-the-nav-element-for-html5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not "bad" but it might be considered best practice to use `<h1>` here instead. Referring to the [first example that W3C documents for the `<nav>` element](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#the-nav-element), they use a `<h1>` within a `<nav>` to describe their navigation menu.

W3C seems to like using `<header>` in other places, such as within the `<body>` or an `<article>` element.

Answer (score 0):

While its possibly not bad.. I would more likely use the following..

```
<section>.    
  <header>blah</header>
  <nav>....</nav>
</section>
```